# How can I automatically use values from a higher-lever(master) visualization when creating a lower-level visualization (details) in Spotfire?

Tags: spotfire

I have several different store regions in a single table. Let's call them A, B, and C.

Right now, the master visualization shows the regions. When I drill down into a specific region, I can see all of the states within that region. The table that shows the states shows the unit percentage as out of 100%, but I want it to be out of the region's unit percentage.

Below is the region view and the current result I am gettting for the states view.

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cl8z1.png)

I want to get the states view to look like this:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nI87.png)

So esssentially, I want the units in a details visualization to automatically divide by the grand total of units in a master visualization in order to get a wholistic Unit % column.

Comment: Can't you just use markings for that? Duplicate the visualisation and check the marker you want to limit your data to

Comment: I don't believe so, because I only want one of the columns in the lower-level visualization to reference the higher-level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your details visualization will only contain **data** from the selection of your master visualization, therefore any calculations in your details visualization can only be based on this data.

However, you could store the value of all units, for all regions, into a property control `Sum([Units])`and reference it in your details visualization like `Sum([Units]) / ${propControl}` where here the units would only be for the selected region.